# Using rlike in org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rlike

I am trying to implement a query in my Scala code which uses a regexp on a Spark `Column` to find all the rows in the column which contain a certain value like:

```
 column.rlike(".*" + str + ".*")
```

`str` is a String that can be anything (except `null` or `empty`).

This works fine for the basic queries that I am testing. However being new to Spark / Scala, I am unsure of if there are any special cases that could break the code here that I need to take care of. Are there any characters that I need to be escaping or special cases that I need to worry about here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be broken by any invalid regexp. You don't even have to try hard:

```
Seq("[", "foo", " ba.r ").toDF.filter($"value".rlike(".*" + "[ " + ".*")).show
```

or can give unexpected results if `str` is a non-trivial pattern itself. For simple cases like this you'll be better with `Column.contains`:

```
Seq("[", "foo", " ba.r ").toDF.filter($"value".contains("[")).show
Seq("[", "foo", " ba.r ").toDF.filter($"value".contains("a.r")).show
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rlike` as zero suggested and `Pattern.quote` to handle the special regex characters.  Suppose you have this DF:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  ("hel?.o"),
  ("bbhel?.o"),
  ("hel?.oZZ"),
  ("bye")
).toDF("weird_string")

df.show()
```

```
+------------+
|weird_string|
+------------+
|      hel?.o|
|    bbhel?.o|
|    hel?.oZZ|
|         bye|
+------------+
```

Here's how to find all the strings that contain `"hel?.o"`.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

df
  .withColumn("has_hello", $"weird_string".rlike(Pattern.quote("hel?.o")))
  .show()
```

```
+------------+---------+
|weird_string|has_hello|
+------------+---------+
|      hel?.o|     true|
|    bbhel?.o|     true|
|    hel?.oZZ|     true|
|         bye|    false|
+------------+---------+
```

You could also add the quote characters manually to get the same result:

```scala
df
  .withColumn("has_hello", $"weird_string".rlike("""\Qhel?.o\E"""))
  .show()
```

If you don't properly escape the regex, you won't get the right result:

```scala
df
  .withColumn("has_hello", $"weird_string".rlike("hel?.o"))
  .show()
```

```
+------------+---------+
|weird_string|has_hello|
+------------+---------+
|      hel?.o|    false|
|    bbhel?.o|    false|
|    hel?.oZZ|    false|
|         bye|    false|
+------------+---------+
```

See [this post](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/advanced-string-matching-with-rlike/) for more details.